# Is it possible to convert the result of NetTrain to a PredictorFunction?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I would like to use `PredictorMeasurements`  on the result of `NetTrain`, but it says it expects a `PredictorFunction` object. So apparently, the output of `NetTrain` is not a `PredictorFunction`.

Am I right? If so, can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In Mathematica 11.1 you can convert your network only into a `ClassifierFunction`. I expect that converting into a `PredictorFunction` will be added in the next releases.

```
net = NetChain[
  {100, 2, SoftmaxLayer[]},
  "Input" -> 100,
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]
  ]

SeedRandom[0];
X = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 100}];
Y = RandomInteger[1, 1000];

net = NetTrain[net, X -> Y, MaxTrainingRounds -> 1]

c = Classify[net]
```

> [image]

**UPDATE**

Yes, it's possible.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169186/23402

Comment: Any idea how to ensure that a net is evaluated with a GPU when applying `ClassifierMeasurements`? Takes forever with a CPU...

Comment: @dan7geo I don't know. Sorry.