# Using PredictorMeasurements with a neural net?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

`PredictorMeasurements` doesn't work with `NetGraph`, here's an example:

```
makeRule[a_, b_] := 
  IntegerString[a] <> "+" <> IntegerString[b] -> a + b;
data = Table[makeRule[i, j], {i, 0, 99}, {j, 0, 99}];
enc = NetEncoder[{"Characters", {DigitCharacter, "+"}}];
net = NetInitialize@
   NetChain[{UnitVectorLayer[], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[40], 
     LongShortTermMemoryLayer[20], SequenceLastLayer[], 
     LinearLayer[]}, "Input" -> enc, "Output" -> "Real"];
PredictorMeasurements[net, data, "Accuracy"]
```

[image]

Is there any way to make this work? Perhaps converting the net into a predictor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look under the hood of `Predict`.

```
p = Predict[{{1, 2} -> 3, {2, 3} -> 4}, 
   Method -> {"NeuralNetwork", "NetworkType" -> "Recurrent"}];

Options[p][[1]]["Model"]["Network"]
```

The network has 2 outputs: mean and log-variance.

[image]

```
Options[p][[1]]["Model"]["Options"]["Network"]["Value"]
```

[image]

Loss function is very interesting:

```
Options[p][[1]]["Model"]["Options"]["LossFunction"]["Value"]
```

[image]

And now let's replace trained network in `Predict` with our custom net.

```
net = NetGraph[
   {
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[40],
    NetMapOperator[LinearLayer[10]],
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[20],
    SequenceLastLayer[],
    LinearLayer[100],
    Ramp,
    LinearLayer[2],
    PartLayer[1 ;; 1],
    PartLayer[2 ;; 2]
    },
   {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> {8, 9}, 
    8 -> NetPort["logvariance"], 9 -> NetPort["mean"]},
   "Input" -> {"Varying", 1}, "logvariance" -> 1, "mean" -> 1
   ] // NetInitialize
```

[image]

```
GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@PredictorFunction
```

We can see that `PredictorFunction` expects `Association` as the input.

```
assoc = Options[p][[1]];
assoc["Model"]["Network"] = net;
p1 = PredictorFunction[assoc]
```

[image]

We can make predictions:

```
p1[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}]
```

> {3.49756, 3.50435}

And we can do `PredictorMeasurements`:

```
pm1 = PredictorMeasurements[p1, {{1, 2} -> 3, {2, 3} -> 4}]
```

[image]

```
pm1["MeanSquare"]
```

> 0.246618

**Addendum**

```
makeRule[a_, b_] := IntegerString[a] <> "+" <> IntegerString[b] -> a + b;
data = Table[makeRule[i, j], {i, 0, 99}, {j, 0, 99}] // Flatten;

enc = NetEncoder[{"Characters", {DigitCharacter, "+"}}];

fe = FeatureExtraction[data[[;; , 1]], enc];

p = Predict[
   data[[-2 ;;, 1]] -> data[[-2 ;;, 2]],
   Method -> {"NeuralNetwork", "NetworkType" -> "Recurrent"},
   FeatureExtractor -> fe
   ];

net = NetGraph[
  {
   (* UnitVectorLayer does not supported because of Standardize as the data processor *)
   LongShortTermMemoryLayer[40],
   LongShortTermMemoryLayer[20],
   SequenceLastLayer[],
   LinearLayer[2],
   PartLayer[1 ;; 1],
   PartLayer[2 ;; 2]
   },
  {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> {5, 6}, 5 -> NetPort["logvariance"], 6 -> NetPort["mean"]}, 
  "Input" -> {"Varying", 1}, "logvariance" -> 1, "mean" -> 1
  ];

loss = Options[p][[1]]["Model"]["Options"]["LossFunction"]["Value"];

net = NetGraph[
   {
    net,
    loss
    },
   {
    NetPort["Input"] -> 1,
    NetPort[1, "logvariance"] -> NetPort[2, "Input1"],
    NetPort[1, "mean"] -> NetPort[2, "Input2"],
    NetPort["Target"] -> NetPort[2, "Target"]
    }
   ];

netT = NetTrain[
   net,
   <|
    "Input" -> (Partition[#, 1] & /@ Standardize /@ enc@data[[;; , 1]]),
    "Target" -> Partition[data[[;; , 2]], 1],
    "Output" -> data[[;; , 2]]
    |>,
   MaxTrainingRounds -> 1
   ];

netT = NetExtract[netT, 1];

assoc = Options[p][[1]];
assoc["Model"]["Network"] = netT;
p1 = PredictorFunction[assoc];

pm1 = PredictorMeasurements[p1, data]
```

Comment: This is great, but what about for my example in question (RNN on text)? I can't get it to work this way... thanks

Comment: @user5601 I was trying to make as simple example as possible. Answer to your question in addendum.

Comment: Thanks for addressing my comment. I'm still unclear on what "UnitVectorLayer does not supported because of Standardize as the data processor" means?

Comment: Also what do the logvariance and mean NetPorts actually compute themselves, and why do we need to give the output to NetTrain? and must we use the loss NetGraph given by Predict, can't we define this arbitrarily?

Comment: 1. I found a way how `UnitVectorLayer` can be used. We can remove some data processors. But there is very strange error. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvVas0AkeAWi0GgEpOWYv9HPswtf

Comment: 2. Yes, I think that logvariance and mean actually compute themselves during minimization of the loss function.

Comment: 3. We can give data to `NetTrain` in forms: {x1->y1, x2->y2} or <|"Input"->{x1,x2},"Output"->{y1,y2}|>. In the first form name "output" is hidden but it exists internally. Because we have custom loss, we give data in second form + additional input port "Target".

Comment: 4. "must we use the loss NetGraph given by Predict, can't we define this arbitrarily?" - It's hard to say. `Predict` creates predictors in terms of mean and variance. So outputs of your network should be also mean and variance. And what will be the loss function, it's up to you.