# Create "PredictorFunction" with NeuralNetwork

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I tried to construct a predictor for a continuous variable using neural networks, something like

*f(a,b,c,d,e) = x,*

trying to predict *x* for a given set of *a,b,c,d,* and *e*.

The builtin `Predict[]` already did a great job, running

`f = Predict[trainingData, Method->"NeuralNetwork"]`.

Because in the end this is just for prototyping, and I want to rebuilt the network "manually", I extracted the layer information, and it looks like this:

[image]

Afterwards I created a `NetChain` to reproduce the results from the `PredictorFunction`

```
net = NetChain[

   Flatten[
    {LinearLayer[50],
     
     Table[{
       LinearLayer[50],
       ElementwiseLayer["SELU"],
       DropoutLayer[0.5]
       }, {i, 
       10}],
     LinearLayer[50], LinearLayer[1]}]
   
   , "Input" -> 5
   ];
```

The problem arises here: After training, my self-made network performs significantly worse (always predicting a value very close to the mean of the training data set), so I guess the training process is significantly different.

```
result = NetTrain[ net, trainingData, All, MaxTrainingRounds -> 20]
f = result["TrainedNetwork"]
```

Is there a significant difference in the training process, if `NetTrain` is used rather than `Predict[]`, or is something else causing the bad performance of my network?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Predict` might be doing some preprocessing on the data. Can you provide an example of the training data or the predictor function as a WMLF file?

Comment: I think you should consider visit this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146440/using-predictormeasurements-with-a-neural-net/169186#169186